# Unable to debug the Application using STMCubeIDE with break points - ST Link

Tags: debugging, stm32cubeide, stm32h7

Our total Flash is divided between Boot Loader and application, and their linker scripts will look like below:

Boot Loader starts at 0x08000000.

The application starts at 0x0804C000.

I'm able to debug the Boot Loader code step by step with breakpoints but not the Application code, Whenever I try as soon as any breakpoint hit STMCubeIDE then the target is restarting immediately.

Debug configuration, pictures attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKAca.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsrE.png)

Target Platform & OS - STM32H7A3ZITB, FreeRTOS

Please suggest, thank you.

I'm able to debug the Boot Loader code step by step with breakpoints but not the Application code, Whenever I try as soon as any breakpoint hit STMCubeIDE then the target is restarting immediately.

Comment: i had a similar (?) issue some weeks ago, and the issue was: I configured the MCU in CubeMX but I forgot to enable SWD in the Hardware Settings. After a Reset the MCU goes into the Bootloader, where the SWD is enabled. After goingg into the GPIO Configuration in the Application the SWD Connection was lost, because the GPIO Config set the SWD Pins to "analog" - as configured in CubeMX with "set all free pins to analog".